# Python: Trying to convert single column from Float to Int

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

new to Python. Playing around with a large dataset in PythonAnywhere. My CSV for some reason brought in the 'Year' as text. I was able to use pd.to_numeric to make it a number. But now it's a float and I want an int. I tried .dropna().apply(np.int64) but it's still coming in as an int. I need the dropna since apparently there are some missing values
code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

movies_df = pd.read_csv("movies_All.csv")

recentdf = movies_df.copy()

recentdf['Year'] = pd.to_numeric(recentdf['Year'], errors = 'coerce')

recentdf['Year'] = recentdf['Year'].dropna().apply(np.int64)

#recentdf = recentdf[recentdf['Year'] > 2000]

print(recentdf['Year'].head())
```

Out: Name: Year, dtype: float64

Comment: Can you please provide some sample input/rows from "movies_All.csv"?

Comment: print(recentdf.head(2)) = `movieId title Year \   1 Toy Story (1995) 1995.0  2 Jumanji (1995) 1995.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused. Based on your given input, your code works for me:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from io import StringIO

input = """
movieId,title,Year
1,Toy Story (1995),1995.0 
2,Jumanji (1995),1995.0
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(input))
df['Year'] = df['Year'].dropna().apply(np.int64)
print(df["Year"].head())
```

Output

```
0    1995
1    1995
Name: Year, dtype: int64
```

Edit: Following the discussion below.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from io import StringIO

input = """
movieId,title,genres
1,Toy Story (1995),Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
2,Jumanji (1995),Adventure|Children|Fantasy
3,Grumpier Old Men (1995),Comedy|Romance
4,Waiting to Exhale (1995),Comedy|Drama|Romance
5,Father of the Bride Part II (1995),Comedy
6,Heat (1995),Action|Crime|Thriller
7,Sabrina (1995),Comedy|Romance
8,Tom and Huck (1995),Adventure|Children
9,Sudden Death (1995),Action
10,GoldenEye (1995),Action|Adventure|Thriller
11,"American President, The (1995)",Comedy|Drama|Romance
12,Dracula: Dead and Loving It (1995),Comedy|Horror
13,Balto (1995),Adventure|Animation|Children
14,Nixon (1995),Drama
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(input))
df["Year"] = df["title"].apply(lambda title: title[-5:-1])
df['Year'] = df['Year'].dropna().apply(np.int64)
print(df["Year"].head())
```

Output

```
0    1995
1    1995
2    1995
3    1995
4    1995
...
Name: Year, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you. I wonder if it's an issue with PythonAnywhere then? I've tried various different methods to change the .datatype() and all still return float64.

Comment: Try inserting `import platform; print(platform.python_version())` into your program and tell us what your output is.

Comment: Output said version was: 3.6.0

Comment: I'm on 3.7.5 but I'm pretty sure that won't make a difference. Otherwise using `numpy==1.17.3` and `pandas==0.23.4`.

Comment: What happens when you execute the code in my answer? Do you still get `dtype: float`?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code and got exactly what your output was, correctly showing int64... which means it's my code and not the platform...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203790/discussion-between-dan-murphy-and-kent-shikama).

Comment: that worked. I put quotes around my strings in the csv which helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure what your example data looks like, but try using

".astype(int)" in stead of ".apply(np.int64)"

This is because the pandas dataframe object consists of numpy arrays. As such, this numpy conversion should work for your operation.

Documentation on this operation can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html).

Answer (score 1):

This rule is valid both for `numpy` and `pandas`. 
Whenever converting the data-type of an array in `numpy` or a column in `pandas`, if `c` is your array or the column (`pandas.Series`), then `c.astype(dtype)` will convert it to the data-type: dtype.

**Examples**:

```
c.astype(bool)
c.astype(np.int64)
c.astype(float)
c.astype(int)
c.astype(np.float32)
```